# Adicionando dinamicamente elemento com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho montado a seguinte estrutura em HTML:

```html
<form name="criaModelo" method='post' action=''>
  <label for="name">
    <strong>Nome:</strong>
    <input name="nomeModelo" type="text">
  </label>

  <h2>Associando Instruções</h2>

  <img src="images/4.png" class="btnNewInst btnHover" title="Inserir nova instrução" />

  <label for="criaAssoc" class="instAssoc">
    <strong>ID:</strong>
    <input type="text">
    <strong>Ordem:</strong>
    <input type="text">

    <span>
      <strong class="instTxt">Instrução:</strong>
      <textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
    </span>
  </label>

  <h2>Associando Tempo</h2>

  <img src="images/4.png" class="btnNewTime btnHover" title="Inserir nova instrução" />

  <label class="time">
    <strong>ID:</strong>
    <input type="text" style="width:25px;">
    <div>
      <strong>Total:</strong>
      <span>12:12:12</span>
      <strong class="margem">Tipo:</strong>
      <span>visível</span>
      <strong class="margem">Momento:</strong>
      <span>12:12:12</span>
      <strong class="margem">Ordem:</strong>
      <span>Crescente</span>
    </div>
  </label>

  <input type="submit" name="btnCriaModelo" class="newbtn" value="Criar"> 
</form>
```

Que tem o seguinte resultado:
[image: Captura de Tela]

Eu queria ao clicar nesse botão ele ir adicionando ao `form` depois do ultimo elemento corrente esse HTML para criar uma nova `label` como acima.

```html
<label for="criaAssoc" class="instAssoc">
  <strong>ID:</strong>
  <input type="text">
  <strong>Ordem:</strong>
  <input type="text">

  <span>
    <strong class="instTxt">Instrução:</strong>
    <textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Você pode usar append do jQuery http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eu sugiro você manter esse `label` como template (i.e. deixe ele no seu estado inicial, vazio e invisível), e [clonar](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) outros a partir dele:

```html
<label id="meuTemplate" for="criaAssoc" class="instAssoc" style="display:none">
    ...
</label>
```

```js
var clone = $("#meuTemplate").clone();
clone.prop("id", novoId); // É necessário mudar o id depois que se clona
```

Então você pode [selecionar o último](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) label e [inserir depois dele](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```js
$(".instAssoc:last").after(clone);
clone.show();
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/8cbp5/).

**Atualização:** para fazer acesso a um determinado elemento **dentro** desse item que você acabou de criar, veja a função [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (ela busca em todos os descendentes). E se quiser que um elemento exclua a si próprio, use a função [`.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) (ou [`.detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), se você pretende reinserir esse elemento no DOM posteriormente; ex.: arrastar-e-soltar / *drag-and-drop*). Exemplo:

```js
clone.find(".botaoExcluir").click(function() {
    clone.remove();
});
```

[Exemplo atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/8cbp5/2/).

Comment: E se eu tivesse um botão dentro de cada label para excluí-la?

Comment: @Luitame A solução mais simples é adicionar o *handler* para tratar do clique no mesmo momento em que você clona. Atualizei a resposta com um exemplo.

Answer (score 5):

Vamos lá, sei que a pergunta é de como seria usando jQuery, porém **prefiro responder como deve ser feito da melhor forma**, já que o que pretende fazer será replicado várias vezes no seu projeto(outras telas com comportamentos similares ou até mesmo mais complexos) e uma biblioteca de MVVM cai como uma luva. Como exemplo, cito a minha preferida **knockoutjs**.

Bibliotecas de [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) abstraem tarefa do programador em ter que sincronizar a interface do usuário com os dados e knockoutjs faz isso de uma forma muito semântica, basicamente é possível criar comportamentos extremamente complexos sem que haja nenhum acoplamento entre os dados que você deseja trabalhar a view.

Como exemplo, fiz este [pequeno plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/YQrKORi7rU7Qg5x8Li51/preview). Clique nas aba "Code" e depois em script.js e depois no index.html e veja como é simples trabalhar com ela.

-----update

Como foi sugerido, segue abaixo todo o código utilizado na solução, que como podem ver, é bem simples e fácil de ser compreendido.

**Javascript**

```
var 
    minhaView = {

        //lista de registros
        registros: ko.observableArray([]),
        id: ko.observable(""),
        ordem: ko.observable(""),

        incluirNovo: function(el) {

          //incluo na lista
          this.registros.push({id: this.id(),ordem: this.ordem()});

          //limpo textboxes
          this.id(""), this.ordem("");
        }
      }

ko.applyBindings(minhaView);
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="txtId">ID</label>
<input type="text" id="txtId" data-bind="value: id" />
<label for="txtOrdem">Ordem:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtOrdem" data-bind="value: ordem"/>
<button data-bind="click: incluirNovo">+</button>
<h2>Relação de itens</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: registros(), visible: registros().length > 0">
    <li>ID: <span data-bind="text: id"></span> - Ordem:<span data-bind="text: ordem"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<span data-bind="visible: registros().length===0">Ainda não existem itens registrados.</span>
```

Comment: Também uso o knockout.js, até pensei logo nele quando vi a pergunta, mas preferi responder usando a tecnologia solicitada. Entretanto, sua sugestão é bastante útil, só sugiro que inclua um código de exemplo (não precisa copiar o plunk todo, só o trecho relevante), pois da forma como está agora [a utilidade da resposta está atrelada ao link](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/215).

Comment: @mgibsonbr, embora não ache que seja necessário, vou atualizar como proposto.